# How can I solve this kind of integrals?

Tags: integration, complex-integration

I=$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2/(2L^2)} e^{-ikx} cos(k_ox)dx$

I know a long technique to solve this integral but I want someone to please suggest me some easy methods (or any book) to solve this kind of integrals.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You basically want to compute the Fourier Transform of $e^{-x^2/(2L^2)}\cos(k_0x)$. Have you tried using the convolution theorem $\mathcal{F}(f\cdot g) = \mathcal{F}(f) \star \mathcal{F}(g)$ ?

Comment: No. I have not. I'll try this method now. Thanks for suggestion.
I was trying to solve this using Cauchy Theorem.

Comment: parseval's theorem is a killer here, since the oscillating parts become delta functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we can evaluate the integral $J(a,b)$ given by

$$\begin{align}
J&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2+ibx}\,dx\\\\
&=e^{-a b^2/4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a(x+ib/2)^2}\,dx\\\\
&=e^{-ab^2/4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-ab^2/4}
\end{align}$$

by completing the square, exploiting Cauchy's Integral Theorem, and evaluating a Gaussian Integral.

Using $\cos(k_0x)=\frac{e^{ik_0x}-e^{-ik_0x}}{2}$, we have

$$I=\frac12 J(1/L,k_0-k)+\frac12J(1/L,-(k+k_0))$$

since

$$I=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/L+i(k_0-k)x}\,dx+\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/L-i(k_0+k)x}\,dx$$

Comment: Otherwise (I think it is more intuitive for those whose don't know the Cauchy integral theorem) you can start with the case $ib \in \mathbb{R}$ and extend to $b \in \mathbb{C}$ with the identity theorem or analytic continuation

Comment: @user1952009 And that is a good idea.  Of course, that requires knowledge of the identity theorem, which might be considered a slightly more advanced concept than Cacuhy's Integral Theorem.

Comment: The Cauchy integral theorem and the identity theorem are complicated for **holomorphic** functions, but they are almost trivial for **analytic** functions.  Here it is obvious the functions are analytic, so the identity theorem is very intuitive : where it converges $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ has only isolated zeros if it is non-identically zero.